# Webdriver get list of children and filter it with xpath

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation

I am getting a list of children of my root WebElement like this:

```
WebElement listOfAddedBuildings = driver.getWebElement("//*[@id=\"right-list\"]/div/mat-list", 10);
List<WebElement> child = listOfAddedBuildings.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
```

But now it returns a list of Elements including elements that I don`t need, how can I modify it to filter and return only elements that contain "h3" tag, but DOES NOT contain "mat-icon" tag, currently I am simply doing it like this, but dont feel like its best way:

```
if (xPath.contains("h3") && !xPath.contains("mat-icon"))
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want `h3` that does not contain `mat-icon`? Or you want *any* child that has `h3` but not `mat-icon`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want *children that have `h3` descendant, but have no `mat-icon` descendant* try:

```
List<WebElement> child = listOfAddedBuildings.findElements(By.xpath("./*[.//h3 and not(.//mat-icon)]"));
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed response, helped a lot.